# Is there a WordPress plug-in that is currently maintained?

Tags: discussion, app-request, wordpress

I joined StackExchange about three weeks ago and I am hooked. I ask and answer questions, and I lurk in many threads.

I have a WordPress-powered website, and I would like to share some questions, answers, and threads on my website. At first, I made WordPress posts from some answers with copy and paste. The process was too time consuming, however, so I stopped.

I see that there were at least two WordPress plugins that allowed some importing of StackExchange material into WordPress. Both of those plugins have not been updated in a long time, though. [All Your Stack Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-your-stack-posts/), Last Updated: 2013-10-1. [StackTack](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stacktack/), Last Updated: 2012-12-1.

I believe a WordPress plugin would help advertise StackExchange because readers of WordPress-powered websites could learn about StackExchange through the questions and answers posted on the various websites.

Comment: Doesn't the Stack Tack plugin still work?